# which means wtype-defaults in haskell?

Tags: haskell

this code causes a warning

```
truncate' :: Maybe Double -> Int -> Maybe Double
truncate' Nothing _ = Nothing
truncate' (Just x) n = Just $ fromIntegral (round (x * t)) / t
  where
    t = 10 ^ n
```

I get this

```
test/Spec.hs:9:31: warning: [-Wtype-defaults]
    • Defaulting the following constraint to type ‘Integer’
        Integral a0 arising from a use of ‘fromIntegral’
    • In the first argument of ‘(/)’, namely
        ‘fromIntegral (round (x * t))’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
        ‘fromIntegral (round (x * t)) / t’
      In the expression: Just $ fromIntegral (round (x * t)) / t
```

Can someone explain the meaning of the warning?

Comment: You are partly reimplementing the `Functor` instance for `Maybe`. Define `truncate'' :: Int -> Double -> Double`, then you can define `truncate' md i = fmap (truncate'' i) md`.

Comment: One fix would be to use `fromInteger` instead of `fromIntegral`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never specify what type `round` will return, so the compiler has to pick one so that it can construct an actual argument to pass to `fromIntegeral`. The warning message is just telling you the compiler picked `Integer` from among all the other types that have `Integral` instances that would have worked just as well.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Specify a concrete type: `fromIntegral (round (x * t) :: Integer)`, for example.

Comment: @chepner The `fromIntegral` is altogether unnecessary—`round :: (RealFrac a, Integral b) => a -> b`. If `fromIntegral` is removed, no explicit type signature is required.

Comment: That too: the explicit return type of `truncate'` itself is sufficient to indicate that `Just` needs from `round`.

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think so. There's immediately a division, and there's nothing that supports both `Integral` and `Fractional`.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah, you're right! Whoops!